# How to nest 2 third-party Wordpress shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm looking to make a progress bar with shortcode that requires a percentage to determine its 'progress'. However, I'm getting my percentage from another piece of shortcode.

When I nest the two shortcodes, they fail. Can someone help me please?
Below is the two code snippets in the plugin's shortcode file, first is the progress bar...

```
function fruitful_pbar_shortcode ($atts, $content = null) {
 $out = $type = $class = '';
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'id'       => 'ffs-pbar-' . rand( 1, 100 ),
      'type'     => '',
      'active'   => false,
      'stripped' => false
 ), $atts));

if (!empty($id))    { $id   = sanitize_html_class($id); }
if (!empty($type))  { $type = sanitize_html_class($type); }
if (!empty($active))  { $active = sanitize_html_class($active); }
if (!empty($stripped))  { $stripped = sanitize_html_class($stripped); }

$class .= $type;
if ($stripped)  { $class  .= ' progress-striped'; }
if ($active)    { $class  .= ' active'; }



$out .= '<div id="'.$id.'" class="progress '.$class.'">';
    $out .= fruitful_sh_esc_content_pbr(do_shortcode($content));
$out .= '</div>';
$out .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
return $out;
}
add_shortcode ("fruitful_pbar", "fruitful_pbar_shortcode");

function fruitful_bar_shortcode ( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $type = $width = '';
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                        'type'  => '',
                        'width' => '60%'
        ), $atts));

        if (!empty($type))  { $type = sanitize_html_class($type); }
        if (!empty($width)) { $width = esc_attr($width); }

        return '<div class="bar '.$type.'" style="width: '.do_shortcode($width).';"></div>';
} 
add_shortcode( 'fruitful_bar', 'fruitful_bar_shortcode', 99 );
```

And second (which is placed after the progress bar) is the get percentage function...

```
if( !function_exists('show_specific_product_quantity') ) {

   function show_specific_product_quantity( $atts ) {

    // Shortcode Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => '', // Product ID argument
        ),
        $atts,
        'product_qty'
    );

    if( empty($atts['id'])) return;

    $stock_quantity = 0;

    $product_obj = wc_get_product( intval( $atts['id'] ) );
    $stock_quantity = ((12000 - $product_obj->get_stock_quantity()) / 12000) * 100;

    if( $stock_quantity > 0 ) return $stock_quantity;

 }
 add_shortcode( 'product_qty', 'show_specific_product_quantity' );
}
```

And below is the shortcode I'm using...

```
[fruitful_pbar][fruitful_bar type="progress-bar-info" width=" [product_qty id="4278"]% " stripped="true"][/fruitful_bar][/fruitful_pbar]
```

As you can see - I'm using a shortcode inside a shortcode to create what I need.
Thanks in advance!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get first shortcode result in one variable and send for second shortcode as a attribute.